# how to encode alternate table rows via XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the structure:

```
<root>
    <relation type="relation1">
        <entityType1>a</entityType1>
        <entityType2>1</entityType2>
        <entityType2>2</entityType2>
        <entityType2>3</entityType2>
    </relation>

    <relation type="relation2">
        <entityType3>b</entityType3>
        <entityType4>7</entityType4>
        <entityType4>8</entityType4>
        <entityType4>9</entityType4>
    </relation>

    <relation type="relation3">
        <entityType5>c</entityType3>
        <entityType6>10</entityType4>
        <entityType6>11</entityType4>
        <entityType6>12</entityType4>
    </relation>
</root>
```

I need to transform via XSLT to a HTML table that contains:

```
<table>
    <tr class="odd"><td>
        a --> 1
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        a --> 2
    </td></tr>

    <tr class="odd"><td>
        a --> 3
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        b --> 7
    </td></tr>

    <tr class="odd"><td>
        b --> 8
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        b --> 9
    </td></tr>

    <tr class="odd"><td>
        c --> 10
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        c --> 11
    </td></tr>

    <tr class="odd"><td>
        c --> 12
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Please note the odd/even alternations of the table's rows. I need to encode those as well via XSLT. Possible?

The basic question is actually how can I keep an index variable to indicate if the current row is odd or even while parsing this structure. 
This would be enough to solve this because I currently have a ... for the 2 relation types and then I iterate via a for-each over relation1/entityType2 and another for for-each over relation2/entityType4.

Thank you!

UPDATE-1:

Please note that the resulting table iterates through both relation1 and relation2 XML elements and it must somehow keep a global index that runs among both type of relations to correctly set the odd/even class when finishing the relation1 iteration and passing to relation2.

UPDATE-2:

Currently I have a code similar to this but I don't know how to easily refactor it to handle the class="odd" setting on tr. The templates Display_Relation currently display the text for relations.

```
<xsl:template match="relation">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@xsi:type, 'relation1')">
                <xsl:for-each select="entityType2">
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Display_Relation1">
                            <xsl:with-param name="source" select="../entityType1/text()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="destination" select="./text()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </td></tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="contains(@xsi:type, 'relation2')">
                <xsl:for-each select="entityType4">
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Display_Relation2">
                            <xsl:with-param name="source" select="../entityType3/text()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="destination" select="./text()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </td></tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="contains(@xsi:type, 'relation3')">
                <xsl:for-each select="entityType6">
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Display_Relation3">
                            <xsl:with-param name="source" select="../entityType5/text()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="destination" select="./text()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </td></tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing a lot of `xsl:for-each`...if you post your XSLT, someone might have a suggestion on a better way. My answer below *should* still work with your `xsl:for-each`'s, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<tr>
  <xsl:if test="boolean((count(preceding::*[parent::relation]) + 1) mod 2)">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</tr>
```

This assumes that the current context is `*[parent::relation]` (entityType1, entityType2, etc.), however the key piece is the use of the `preceding::` axis.

If you wanted, you could also use something like `preceding::*[starts-with(name(),'entityType')]` instead of `preceding::*[parent::relation]`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I appreciate it! About your comment, I've attached the current code in UDPATE-2. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this. If you iterate through your first `<relation>`'s child elements using `<xsl:for-each>`, you can use the `position()` function to get the row number, and then test it for oddness.

```
<xsl:for-each select="relation[@type='relation1']/*">
<tr>
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>

<!-- etc. -->

</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check UPDATE-1 for more context on the issue.